# SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function AND TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord.js, ytdl

I have tried to get a result but I can't find how to solve `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

```
static async searchYoutube(query, message, voiceChannel) {
    await youtube.searchVideos(query, 5).catch(videos => {
      await message.say(
        ':x: There was a problem searching the video you requested!'
      );
      return;
    });
    if (videos.length < 5 || !videos) {
      message.say(
        `:x: I had some trouble finding what you were looking for, please try again or be more specific.`
      );
      return;
    }
```

Now, they also recommended color async on the front, I did it but it marks another error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

```
static async searchYoutube(query, message, voiceChannel) {
    await youtube.searchVideos(query, 5).catch(async (videos) => {
      await message.say(
        ':x: There was a problem searching the video you requested!'
      );
      return;
    });
    if (videos.length < 5 || !videos) {
      message.say(
        `:x: I had some trouble finding what you were looking for, please try again or be more specific.`
      );
      return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ad `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function` – this is pretty much self explanatory error, however, there's no need to `await` for `message.say(...)` in either of these cases.

Ad `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` – this is because `videos` on line 8 is not defined anywhere but inside (and only inside of) that `.catch` block.

I'd recommend using `.then` block same way you use `.catch` in order to process  `searchVideos` results. The code is asynchronous (is run concurrently), but the wrapper function itself doesn't need to be `async`.

```js
static searchYoutube(query, message, voiceChannel) {
  youtube.searchVideos(query, 5)
    .then(videos => {
      if (!videos || videos.length < 5) // first check !videos, then videos.length
        message.say(`:x: I had some trouble finding what you were looking for, please try again or be more specific.`)
      else {
        ... // continue your code
      }
    })
    .catch(error => { // catch gives an error, not the result
      message.say(':x: There was a problem searching the video you requested!')
    })
}
```

Comment: It keeps marking my mistake and I already did what you told me, and I say it from now on, that same code (mine) previously served to perfection, I leave here the fullcode where marks it [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/k3K4rhdx) Thanks

Comment: Seems the problems are elswehere. On what line numbers are the errors thrown?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, it doesn't send the error to the console

Comment: Try with `try { ... } catch (e) { console.warn(e) }` block. There might be other errors in your code, you need to be able to catch them.

Comment: More errors: `vidNameArr.push` on lines 10 and 20 (of Pastebin example) will throw an error, because `vidNameArr` is a const. Also, if `message.channel.send()` on line 33 is an async function, then `var songEmbed` will be a (pending?) Promise and `songEmbed.delete()` will throw an error.